# ¿Es posible omitir "que" en "supongo que irás"?

Tags: gramática

Tengo el vicio de escribir

> "supongo irás mañana"

o bien

> "creo te queda bien ese color".

Sé que es correcto decir "supongo **que** irás mañana" y "creo **que** te queda bien ese color", pero no sé si omitiendo el `que` estoy incurriendo en un error.

¿Hay una razón concreta para dejar el `que`?

Comment: Me parece una pregunta muy interesante y útil. Fíjate, yo pensaba que era incorrecto y sin embargo no lo es. Thank you for your question!

Comment: @MaríaCC yo también pensé que lo era. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cito del María Moliner:

> El "que" conjunción completiva que introduce un complemento directo puede elidirse; especialmente con verbos de opinión o sentimiento [...] Pero se recomienda como más elegante la forma completa.